# Update with Data Source Control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net-datasourcecontrol

How do you run an update query in a data source control from a button?  I have the data source control with the update query configured in it.  I just don't know what to put in the button_click event to make it run.

Answer (score 1):

In the event handler just call the Update method for your Datasource control.

Answer (score 1):

aha   I needed parenthesis after the update command

sdsUpdateName.Update();

Answer (score -1):

I get an error when I call the Update method of the Datasource

sdsUpdateName.Update;

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement